# change color of div depending numeric value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 15 divs with the same class but different id and i want to change the color of the value.

For example, if one or five div's value is under 15 the color of the value will be red, if three or one the value of it is up to 15 but under 45 the color of the value is green and if the value of the div is up to 45 the color will be yellow but all of the colors i want to see at the same time.

My div's are like this:

```
<div id="listado">
  <div id="cuautitlan" class="dfedo">15</div>
  <div id="coacalco" class="dfedo">54</div>
  <div id="atizapan" class="dfedo">65</div>
  <div id="tlalne" class="dfedo">2</div>
  <div id="tlalne2" class="dfedo">5</div>
  <div id="naucalpan" class="dfedo">90</div>
  <div id="neza" class="dfedo">105</div>
  <div id="huixqui" class="dfedo">65</div>
  <div id="azca" class="dfedo">75</div>
  <div id="gustavo" class="dfedo">45</div>
  <div id="miguel" class="dfedo">35</div>
  <div id="cuauh" class="dfedo">2</div>
  <div id="venus" class="dfedo">1</div>
  <div id="coaji" class="dfedo">58</div>
  <div id="alvaro" class="dfedo">5</div>
  <div id="benito" class="dfedo">95</div>
  <div id="izta" class="dfedo">43</div>
  <div id="magda" class="dfedo">35</div>
  <div id="coyoacan" class="dfedo">33</div>
  <div id="iztapa" class="dfedo">65</div>
  <div id="tlalpan" class="dfedo">89</div>
  <div id="xochi" class="dfedo">99</div>
  <div id="tlahuac" class="dfedo">9</div>
  <div id="milpa" class="dfedo">0</div>
</div>
```

My jquery is like this

```
$("div.dfedo").each(function()
                  {
                    $(this).value < 15 ? $(this).css('color','red');
                  });
```

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj4c40qq/)

Comment: Please note that a `div` doesn't has a `value` attribute, therefore you cannot use `$().value` here. You can use the `$().text()` function instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/pj4c40qq/1/

```
$("div.dfedo").each(function() {
  $(this).html() < 15 ? $(this).css('color', 'red') : null;

  ($(this).html() >= 15 && $(this).html() < 45) ? $(this).css('color', 'green'): null;

  $(this).html() >= 45 ? $(this).css('color', 'yellow') : null;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.colorize = function () {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this), number = $this.text();
      $this.css({color: number < 15 ? "red"
                      : number < 45 ? "green"
                      : "yellow"});
   });
};
```

And just run:

```
$("div.dfedo").colorize();
```

See [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rsp/xk1ruz8v/).

Making a jQuery plugin for things like these is a good habit. That way you can reuse your code easily and do interesting things like this:

```
$("div.dfedo").hide().colorize().show("slow");
```

By making a simple plugin you basically make a new jQuery command that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was on the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
$('div.dfedo').each(function() {
    var $elem = $(this),
        val = $elem.html(),
        color = (val < 15) 
            ? 'red' 
            : (val >= 15 && val < 45) 
                ? 'green' 
                : 'yellow';
  
    $elem.css('color', color);
});
```

```css
.dfedo {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listado>    
    <div id="cuautitlan" class="dfedo">15</div>
    <div id="coacalco" class="dfedo">54</div>
    <div id="atizapan" class="dfedo">65</div>
    <div id="tlalne" class="dfedo">2</div>
    <div id="tlalne2" class="dfedo">5</div>
    <div id="naucalpan" class="dfedo">90</div>
    <div id="neza" class="dfedo">105</div>
    <div id="huixqui" class="dfedo">65</div>
    <div id="azca" class="dfedo">75</div>
    <div id="gustavo" class="dfedo">45</div>
    <div id="miguel" class="dfedo">35</div>
    <div id="cuauh" class="dfedo">2</div>
    <div id="venus" class="dfedo">1</div>
    <div id="coaji" class="dfedo">58</div>
    <div id="alvaro" class="dfedo">5</div>
    <div id="benito" class="dfedo">95</div>
    <div id="izta" class="dfedo">43</div>
    <div id="magda" class="dfedo">35</div>
    <div id="coyoacan" class="dfedo">33</div>
    <div id="iztapa" class="dfedo">65</div>
    <div id="tlalpan" class="dfedo">89</div>
    <div id="xochi" class="dfedo">99</div>
    <div id="tlahuac" class="dfedo">9</div>
    <div id="milpa" class="dfedo">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, `$(this).css('color', $(this).text() < 15 ? 'red' : 'initial');`

Comment: If i want to change de color for number up to 15 and equal or lower to 45 change the color for yellow, without lost the other one?

Comment: @victor Updated the answer to to change de color for number up to 15 and equal or lower to 45 change the color for yellow